# Cleaner way of writing multiple conditional statements

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, conditional-statements

I need to ask if you guys can find a much cleaner way of rewriting this code. I can't see to make it possible

**Update 2 (After some time and super power mind I come up with this. I am sure there is more room to improve)**

```js
const uploadedFiles = images.map((item, index) => {
      if (images.length < 2) {
        if (item.file.name.match(/.(gif)$/i)) {
          return (
            <ImageGif
              key= {index}
              src= {item.blobUrl}
              onClose={this.props.removeImage}
            />
          );
        }

        return (<ImageContainer
          src={item.blobUrl}
          key={index}
          id={index}
          onClose={this.props.removeImage}
        />);
      }

      if (MAX_SIZE === index + 1) {
        return (<ImageContainer
            src={item.blobUrl}
            key={index}
            id={index}
            onClose={this.props.removeImage}
            hiddenImages={hiddenImages}
          />);
      }
      return (<ImageContainer
            src={item.blobUrl}
            key={index}
            id={index}
            onClose={this.props.removeImage}
          />);
    });
```

Would really appreciate any directions. Have a good day.

Comment: If you're returning inside a conditional, you don't need the else statements.

Comment: @evolutionxbox ohh i get it. instead of `else if`  I should use only `if` right?

Comment: Try and reduce the the conditional thinking. Make it as simple as possible.

Comment: If this code works, and you're just looking for a cleanup, [CodeExchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is probably the best place for this question

Comment: Sure, thank you. I will try there, however I think I should give another chance of trying to do it myself :D

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it.

```
const uploadedFiles = images.map((item, index) => {
    const imageContainer = <ImageContainer
                                src={item.blobUrl}
                                key={index}
                                id={index}
                                onClose={this.props.removeImage}
                            />;

    if (images.length >= 2) {
        if (MAX_SIZE === index + 1) {
            return (
                <ImageContainer
                    src={item.blobUrl}
                    key={index}
                    id={index}
                    onClose={this.props.removeImage}
                    hiddenImages={hiddenImages}
                />
            );
        }

        return { imageContainer };
    }
    else {
        if (images.length < 2) {
            if (item.file.name.match(/.(gif)$/i)) {
                return (
                    <ImageGif
                        key= {index}
                        src= {item.blobUrl}
                        onClose={this.props.removeImage}
                    />
                );
            }

            return { imageContainer };
        }
    }

    return null;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
const uploadedFiles = images.map((item, index) => {
  const imageContainer = <ImageContainer
      src={item.blobUrl}
      key={index}
      id={index}
      onClose={this.props.removeImage}
    />;

  if (images.length < 2) {
    if(item.file.name.match(/.(gif)$/i)){
    return (
      <ImageGif
        key= {index}
        src= {item.blobUrl}
        onClose={this.props.removeImage}
      />
    );}
    return { imageContainer };
  } 
  else {
     if (MAX_SIZE === index + 1) {
      return (<ImageContainer
          src={item.blobUrl}
          key={index}
          id={index}
          onClose={this.props.removeImage}
          hiddenImages={hiddenImages}
        />);
    }
    return { imageContainer };
  }

  return null;
});
```